# Vulnerable XSS Test

Tags: xss

I have to do a presentation about XSS. 
I want to give a demo but I can't find test platforms.
I found http://zero.webappsecurity.com/index.html but this site always shows a FireHost-block when I try to run a script in the searchbox.

Is there someone who knows the reason for this issue? Does someone have a list of legal XSS vulnerable websites?

Comment: What about a VM? There are many purposely vulnerable VM for testing purposes.

Comment: What about http://www.xssed.com/?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for lists, which can become stale or out-of-date over time.

Answer (score 0):

There are many sites on which you can perform the XSS attack. Some sites are demo.testfire.net, hax.tor.hu, hackthissite.org, astalavista.com. You can use demo.testfire.net which is maintained by IBM and is used for Appscan demo.

Comment: I already tried testfire and it's a very handy site. But the problem is the fact I can't mail the stolen cookie to myself. I don't know the reason why it won't work. I can't even receive an empty mail from it. But my webserver with php does work. It worked on other platforms like bwapp.

Comment: demo.testfire.net is a demo site which is not connected to any mail server so such attacks cant take place. For showing how the XSS attack occurs you can use a simple payload.

Comment: Ow thanks for the info. Do you recommend some VM which works with a mailserver?

Comment: There is no VM as such that has a connection to the mail server( for security purpose). You can use Damn Vulnerable Web Application from OWASP which is a VM and is vulnerable.

Answer (score 0):

Acunetix provides some web applications to test.

Maybe you can use some of them to show XSS on different scenarios: http://www.vulnweb.com/

Answer (score 0):

There are special linux distro, such as badstore. It is vulnerable web store. Also damn vulnerable linux provides good web quizzes.

Answer (score 0):

you should check out OWASP as it directly relates to your presentation. Specifically to answer your question, you should check out OWASP WebGoat project is its is a deliberately insecure web application designed to teach web app security. (And contains XSS vulns, among many others) You can download it from here: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_WebGoat_Project

Additionally, it isn't difficult demonstrate an XSS vulnerability if you have basic programming knowledge. (PHP,ASP,Python). Create a page that asks for input, have it post to a second page that takes that input and displays it back on the page. In php it would be something like this:

**index.php:**

```
<? 
   if ( isset($_POST["posted"])) {
       $name = $_POST["name"];
   }

?>
<html>
<body>
<? if (isset($name)) { 
  echo "Hello, <b>" . $name . "</b>";
?>
<form action="index.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="name" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="posted" value="1">
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```